# Why is there excessive question editing?

Tags: discussion, editing

My question was edited so that it is no longer a question but a statement with a question mark at the end. People making edits should be editing for clarity and spelling/grammar errors, not to their personal preferences to gain "points". All edits made to my question were superfluous. I think that editing to this degree drives people away from the site as their words get changed everytime they open their mouths.

[image]

Link to the edits: https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/271634/revisions

Comment: Although I agree with the sentiments expressed here (+1), I don't see any question: at the moment this post is just a complaint.  Is there a question you would like to ask?

Comment: still looks like a question to me

Comment: @whuber i made it a question now. but it is kind of a complaint which is why i brought it to meta.

Comment: @Ian Turton it is not really though, it is now a statement with a question mark at the end, why did that edit even need to be made? i am not explaining how to do this i am asking how to do this. if you want people to have cofidence in your stack exchange you need to focus on making edits that help the question, not just seeking "points".

Comment: Meta is not really for ranting or airing complaints: it's a little bit more controlled than that.  I found that reviewing the help at https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta was helpful.  As far as your question in its current form goes, what are you trying to achieve (if anything)?  Do you have a suggestion to improve our site?  A question about how it works?

Comment: @whuber well my question is why is there excessive editing? as stated above. i am trying to help and improve the site by not making people feel like they are being nitpicked and that only valuable edits are made.

Comment: please re-read my meta question i am not complaining i am asking and so far no one has been able to provide any answers.

Comment: @whuber please take this off of on-hold i improved it to your suggestions.

Comment: *not to their personal preferences to gain "points"* - What points are you referring to?  Other than when first starting out on SE I am not aware of being able to gain any points for edit posts.

Comment: I also think there is excessive editing, but disagree in this specific example. The edit made by @PolyGeo had improved question's readability and searchability, in my opinion. The excessive editing to me happens when many questions are edited in a row without them being addressed in all their aspects (title/body/tags). Have already expressed this POV in some posts in GIS Meta, e.g., [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/reaching-80-000-answered-questions-before-questions-on-our-site-reaches-100-000/4781#4781).

Comment: Agree that this drives people away from the site, but at this point I'm afraid not much can be done about it. When I see superfluous edits without explanation on my posts, I just roll them back.

Comment: I appreciate your comment at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/why-is-there-excessive-question-editing#comment8994_4822 and that you have now adopted the edits that I made to that question. I thank you for bringing your concerns to Meta GIS SE, and hope that I have not undone our more mutual understanding of the SE model by the edits that I have just applied to this Meta question to try and remove the "rant/complaint" aspect. I perceive that you have moved away from that. Editing Meta GIS SE posts is something I do far less than editing GIS SE posts, and generally try to avoid.

Comment: Rolled back to revision 3, as last edit biased the question which had a critical POV about excessive/unecessary/superfluous editing, to a general question about how the system works regarding editing. The edit changes in my opinion how votes on question are understood by readers from agreeing with OP (or a neutral position, like being an interesting discussion) to a neutral position (or not agreeing with OP; i.e, that there is not excessive editing).

Comment: @AndreSilva considering the discussion that the asker and I had last night in comments here and my presenting why I was editing I think your rollback is counter-productive to the site.  I think the asker's "POV about excessive/unecessary/superfluous editing" no longer applies as evidenced by them having changed their cited question to match the edits initially considered "excessive/unecessary/superfluous".  None of the answers say that my original edits were "excessive/unecessary/superfluous".  It is only temporary comments that have that perspective.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I don’t think it is counter-productive. The question goes beyond you and OP. It already had 12 votes (net score +8). The edit changes the question (we should avoid radical changes and changes that alter the question’s meaning). Despite, I supported your edit in OP’s question (the one in main GIS SE) and upvoted your answer here; I don’t think editing a question as you did here in Meta is correct (as explained in previous comment).

Comment: @AndreSilva As long as question edits don't invalidate any existing answers, and are in line with what appears to be the asker's evolved point of view, then surely a probing edit to assess whether that is the asker's current question is reasonable, in order to present users and visitors to the site with a clear and objective question (no longer a rant or a complaint) to vote on.  If that means any original voters wish to change their vote, then that is the reason for edits unlocking the option for them to do so.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I am not convinced; your edit changed this question. OP claimed your edit on main was superfluous; you added a “seem” where there was a “were”. Editing a question frequently in a meaningful way is different than execessively editing (in the sense of being superfluous) once. I am not discussing the merit if that edit in the main was superfluous or not, but I am defending OP’s POV here should be preserved.

Comment: @AndreSilva have you seen that w.r.t. the original question on Main the asker rolled back to my edit, asked the Meta question, chatted in comments with me in Meta, then reinstated my edit to the Main question.  If they have not changed their mind about whether my original edits were "excessive/unecessary/superfluous" then why reinstate them?  Of course my edit to the Meta question changed it to a position that I believe reflects the current position of its asker, does not strand either answer, allows voters to reconsider their votes, and would leave the site with something perhaps FAQ-worthy.

Comment: @AndreSilva Is there somewhere that you have read that within wiki-style editing of a question here or on Main that an asker's original point of view must be locked in stone?  Surely, we all want the opportunity to review our positions on any issue as we grow to understand more about it over time.  I think the asker should gain great respect from the community for being prepared to reconsider the advice I offered on the Main question in the form of an edit.

Comment: You well know participation in GIS Meta is low, and chances of people re-reading posts is also low. Editing questions like this is a clear attempt to game the system; and goes against to what is recommended (radical changes/changes of meaning). Editing a question in this fashion just because he/she talked to OP in some second class citizen venue (comments or chat) does not make sense (it is not transparent). There are better ways to address such follow up conversations: the OP can accept your answer; cam edit his/her own question and add a note emphasizing a change in POV. continues...

Comment: Otherwise you are forcing/pushing a situation to overrule everybody else’s opinion with yours (peple who already voted). @PolyGeo.

Comment: @AndreSilva I wish you would give some benefit of your doubt here. I feel like the asker and I have gone to considerable effort to turn a situation from site disharmony towards possible consensus and have done so with full transparency to the community. We have not gone off to chat nor deleted any of our comments. We each explained our reasonings here in Q&A&comments and I felt were in the process of finalizing, with expedience, a common understanding of why question titles are frequently edited.

Comment: maybe the question would be better served by an answer that addressed the information you passed on to me in the comments of your answer below @PolyGeo? instead of changing the original question to solve the problem?  an answer that pointed out the fact that this is a wiki style site and the reasons edits are made? with that link to the tour in it?

Comment: @gomapping It's late here now but I'll try to improve my answer or write a second one tomorrow. I was hoping not to spend a lot more time on this question by working from the question end first. I'd really like to try and turn this into an FAQ if we can, because editing is such an important part of SE Q&A that any misunderstanding of its purpose can act as a drag on its effectiveness.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I doubt this question will evolve into a [faq] because the answers were not so well received, specially yours (but I hope I am wrong). Despite I endorsed your answer, I think some people thinks the speech and actions are not aligned. You write about editing the entire post for clarity and improvement, but we know most times you make many partial edits in a row. continues...

Comment: To me, that is the potential root cause of perceived excessive editing in our site. Just as a comparison, in Stack Overflow you would be [top #4 editor](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). Considering they have 163 times more questions than we do, this can't be a good statistic to GIS SE. Your user logo frequently floods the active page, and when I see only part of the post was edited I think the editing feature is being misused, because bumping questions to the active page removes time of visibility from new answers.

Comment: It's hard to counter a criticism based on volunteering too much time.

Comment: If anyone is keen to find new answers this is a link that I have bookmarked: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer

Comment: An alternative to using a bookmark to find new answers forever is to upvote the Meta SE feature request at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235102/finding-questions-with-the-newest-answers-anywhere-on-site

Comment: I also posted about this here: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/why-does-the-active-queue-show-old-answered-questions-when-edited

Answer (score 10):

At the beginning of this site, we aimed to have full-sentence questions as titles, as described in  [Using questions as titles?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/using-questions-as-titles?rq=1)

> A good title is formulated as a question, is grammatically correct, uses consistent capitalization, occupies one line or less, and clearly indicates the main point.

Later, it was questioned if having 1000s of question starting with "How to ..." actually adds clarity to the site. (Cannot find the reference now)

Comment: I have rolled back the edits back to the original question. The community is still seeking guidance on this subject: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5089/8104